# Car fueling problem in java. Can anyone figure out any error in while loop condition?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, while-loop, greedy

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CarFueling {
 static int compute_refills(int dist,int tank,int stops[],int n){
    
        int current_refills=0;
        int num_refills=0;
        int last_refill=0;
        while(current_refills<=n) {
             last_refill = current_refills;
            while ((current_refills <= n) && (stops[current_refills + 1] - stops[last_refill]) <= tank) {
                current_refills = current_refills + 1;
            }

            if (current_refills == last_refill)
                return -1;
            if (current_refills <= n)
                num_refills = num_refills + 1;


        }
        return num_refills;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dist = scanner.nextInt();
        int tank = scanner.nextInt();
       int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int stops[] = new int[n*n*n];// to solve array index out of bound exception increase the size of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            stops[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

       System.out.println(compute_refills(dist,tank,stops,n));

    }
}
```

I think there is some issue in my while loop condition.
Input:
950
400
4
200 375 550 750
my output:
1
correct output:
2

Comment: new int[n*n*n] ... seriously?

Comment: I have just increased the size of array by doing this

Comment: Change all the addition being done to either increment or += 1

Comment: @Stultuske can your plz clear my doubts??

Comment: @ShivanshPotdar can you plz explain it?

Comment: Instead of doing current_refill = current_refill + 1         do
current_refill += 1                or
current_refill ++

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the

> ```
> (current_refills <= n) && (stops[current_refills + 1] ... )
> ```

part, two things:

- `current_refills <= n` is true for both `n-1` (the last element of a n-element array, as the first one has index 0), and `n` (which is already outside the array)
- then `stops[current_refills + 1]` accesses an element "later", which is 1 or 2 elements above the max for these two cases

But actually this can work, just you could add 0 for the beginning of the trip and `dist` as the end:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
int stops[] = new int[n+2];
stops[0] = 0; // well, it is 0 already
stops[n+1] = dist;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    stops[i] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Then `compute_refills()` may work correctly (though I haven't checked).

Comment: Well, it makes no change . There is some issue in computation of while loop . It's not running well

Comment: External while loop running for one time only I think there is no increment in answer. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Tobbin: https://ideone.com/7OdDkc has the proposed changes and it a) works without crashing b) prints 2 as output.